# Why linux split program have weird behavior with large files >20GB?

Tags: linux, split

I'm doing the next statement on my ubuntu:

```
split --number=l/5 /pathToSource.csv /pathToOutputDirectory
```

If i do a "ls"

```
myUser@serverNAme:/pathToOutputDirectory> ls -la

total 21467452 
drwxr-xr-x 2 myUser group        4096 Jun 23 08:51 .
drwxrwxrwx 4 myUser group        4096 Jun 23 08:44 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 myUser group 10353843231 Jun 23 08:48 aa
-rw-r--r-- 1 myUser group           0 Jun 23 08:48 ab
-rw-r--r-- 1 myUser group 11376663825 Jun 23 08:51 ac
-rw-r--r-- 1 myUser group           0 Jun 23 08:51 ad
-rw-r--r-- 1 myUser group   252141913 Jun 23 08:51 ae
```

If i do a "du" over ab and ad files.

```
$du -h ab ad
0   ab
0   ad
```

As you can see, split divided the file in a non-homogeneous form.
Anyone know what's going on?
Some unprintable character can hang the split?
Thank you.
Best Regards!
Francisco.

Comment: > wc -l a*
      44508 aa
          0 ab
      62377 ac
          0 ad
      85713 ae
     192598 total

Comment: I have an amount of 192598 lines in total. aa have 44508 lines, ac have 62377 lines and ae have 85713 lines. But I have an anormal line that have more of 450MiB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is unusual data with an average line length of 114137, I'm not sure that fully describes the issue. Hmm you've 21982648969 of data => each bucket that split is trying to fill is 4396529793. That's larger than 2^32. I wonder do we have a 32 bit overflow. Are you on a 32 bit or 64 bit platform? Looking at the code I don't see an overflow issue TBH. Note you could anonymize and compress the data providing the following file for download somewhere:

```
tr -c '\n' . < /pathToSource.csv | xz > /pathToSource.csv.xz
```

It's also worth specifying the version since implementation changed a bit between v8.8 and v8.13

Comment: i realize an "uname -a" kernel 3.8.0-35-generic, x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Comment: split --version show
split (GNU coreutils) 8.13. 
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.  i 've notified yesterday to my source he solve his code. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I don't understand. What did you do to fix it?

Comment: I sanitize the file before split it.

Answer (score 0):

A workarround in groovy:

```
class Sanitizer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    def textOnly = new File('/path/NoDanger.txt')
    def data = new File('/path/danger.txt')
    String line = null
    data.withReader { reader ->
      while (  ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null  ){
        /*char[] stringToCharArray = line.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
          char a = stringToCharArray[i]
          int b = Character.getNumericValue(a);
          println Integer.toHexString(b)
            if (!(b =~ /\w/)) {
              println "inside" 
            } else println "outside" 
        }*/
        String newString = line.replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}]", "");
        textOnly << newString+"\n"
      }
    } //reader 
  }

}
```